# Recreating backstack with Android Navigation Architecture Component

Tags: android, back-stack, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to implement navigation to specific Detail pages of my app using PendingIntent from a notification, however I am having problems recreating the backstack from the Detail page all the way back to the start destination.

I made a sample app [here](https://github.com/limdale/nav-backstack-test) with a single activity and three fragments to demo this:

```
Fragment 1   ->   Fragment 2  ->  Fragment 3
(start dest) <-               <-
```

From Fragment 1 (the start destination), I navigate directly to Fragment 3 using

```
    Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.fragment2,
            null,
            NavOptions.Builder()
                    .build())
```

From Fragment 3, when I call `Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()` I am navigated back to Fragment 1. Is there a way to get this to navigate to a newly created Fragment 2 instead?

Comment: this is the expected behavior when call navigatesUp() from fragment 3 to go to fragment 1 because this is the fragment on a stack and fragment 2 not created yet. 
so if you want to change this behavior you should do it manually because navigateUp() go to the previous fragment.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to M.G for pointing to the right direction, I have managed to solve this by manually creating the backstack using the navigation library. This means sequentially calling `findNavController(...).navigate(...)` multiple times to create a backstack.

For example when I deep link to fragment 3 but want an up navigation back to fragments 1 and 2, I call:

```
findNavController.navigate(R.id.fragment1, ...)
findNavController.navigate(R.id.fragment2, ...)
findNavController.navigate(R.id.fragment3, ...)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining where you would call this if you navigated to `fragment3` using a deeplink?