# Creating back stack with Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-editor

I am having an issue creating a back stack with the new android navigation component. I have a main graph with a splash fragment, a loginregister root fragment that has it's own graph, an onboard step 1 fragment with corresponding step 1 graph, step2 fragment with step 2 graph, and a home fragment. When the user logs in, they can go to either step1, step2, or the home. If they go to step2, I want them to be able to hit back and end up at step1, and even better, the last fragment of the step1 graph. I've tried setting global actions and setting popTo, but I often get an error saying that it's ignoring the popTo because step1 isn't part of the back stack. Having a button on the screen to go back so I can call navigate with global action works, but when using the hard back button it will go from step2 to login/register.

Even just a simple case of one graph, fragments A, B, C, D. The user can enter the app at any fragment. If I just try to navigate to fragment C with the BtoC action, then there is an error of this action is unknown to this controller. Currently I have to essentially make a couple navigate calls, one after another.

In on of the navigation training docs it says "And in both cases, you should make the Back button more predictable by inserting into the task's back stack the complete upward navigation path to the app's topmost screen. " But I can't find anywhere that really shows how to do this with the NavController and single activity apps.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you having trouble with bottom navigation components?@salbury

Comment: No, not using bottom navigation...

Comment: How is there no suggestions for this yet? This seems like a common use case.

Comment: "_If I just try to navigate to fragment C with the BtoC action, then there is an error of this action is unknown to this controller._" I think it would be helpful if you posted some part of your code

Comment: please try to post code

Comment: I have the same issue and unfortunately I can't find any good solutions. Here's one workaround which is _okay_ I guess: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55023042/2933028